# First click on button has an odd behaviour

Tags: scala, scala.js, scala-cats, scalajs-react

I am working on a todo list app using

- scalajs,
- cats (free monads), and
- scalajs-react

When I am using a simple model like the code below, everything works like expected.

```scala
class TodoModel() {
  private object State {
    var todos = Seq.empty[Todo]

    def mod(f: Seq[Todo] => Seq[Todo]): Callback = {
      val newTodos = f(todos)
      Callback(todos = newTodos)
    }
  }

  def add(t: Todo): Callback = State.mod(_ :+ t)
  def todos: Seq[Todo] = State.todos
}
```

Once I use the free monads from cats, I have an odd behaviour. The first click always inserts two todo entries. Every click afterwards works like expected. See the pictures below.

What is wrong here?

```scala
import cats.free.Free
import cats.free.Free.liftF
import japgolly.scalajs.react._
import japgolly.scalajs.react.vdom.html_<^._
import org.scalajs.dom

case class Todo(text: String)

sealed trait TodoModelOp[A]
case class Add(todo: Todo) extends TodoModelOp[Unit]
case class Todos() extends TodoModelOp[Seq[Todo]]

object FreeTodoModelOps {
  // type alias for lifted TodoModelOp
  type TodoModelOpF[A] = Free[TodoModelOp, A]

  def add(Todo: Todo): TodoModelOpF[Unit] = liftF[TodoModelOp, Unit](Add(Todo))
  def todos: TodoModelOpF[Seq[Todo]] = liftF[TodoModelOp, Seq[Todo]](Todos())
}

object StateInterpreter {
  import cats.arrow.FunctionK
  import cats.{ Id, ~> }

  val interpet: TodoModelOp ~> Id = new (TodoModelOp ~> Id) {
    val todos = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Todo]

    def apply[A](fa: TodoModelOp[A]): Id[A] = fa match {
      case Add(todo) => todos += todo; ()
      case Todos() => todos.toSeq
    }
  }

}

class TodoModel() {
  import cats.instances.list._
  import cats.syntax.traverse._
  import FreeTodoModelOps._

  def add(t: Todo): Callback = {
    def program: TodoModelOpF[Unit] = for {
      _ <- FreeTodoModelOps.add(t)
    } yield ()

    Callback(program.foldMap(StateInterpreter.interpet))
  }

  def todos: Seq[Todo] = {
    def program: TodoModelOpF[Seq[Todo]] = for {
      n <- FreeTodoModelOps.todos
    } yield n

    program.foldMap(StateInterpreter.interpet)
  }
}

object TodoPage {

  case class Props(model: TodoModel)

  case class State(todos: Seq[Todo])

  class Backend($: BackendScope[Props, State]) {
    val t = Todo("a new todo")

    def onSubmit(e: ReactEventFromInput) =
      e.preventDefaultCB >>
        $.modState(s => State(s.todos :+ t)) >>
        $.props.flatMap(P => P.model.add(t))

    def render(S: State) =
      <.div(
        <.form(
          ^.onSubmit ==> onSubmit,
          <.button("Add #", S.todos.length + 1)),
        <.ul(S.todos.map(t => <.li(t.text)): _*))

  }

  val component = ScalaComponent.builder[Props]("Todo")
    .initialStateFromProps(p => State(p.model.todos))
    .renderBackend[Backend]
    .build

  def apply(model: TodoModel) = component(Props(model))
}

object Test {
  val model = new TodoModel()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    TodoPage.apply(model).renderIntoDOM(dom.document.getElementById("mount-node"))
  }
}
```

**empty, no click on button**
[image: empty]

**first click on button**
[image: first click]

**second click on button**
[image: second click]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first snippet there's a bug:

Here you've got a variable `todos` (inpure) which you're accessing in a pure context:

```
def mod(f: Seq[Todo] => Seq[Todo]): Callback = {
  val newTodos = f(todos)
  Callback(todos = newTodos)
```

Impurity should be in `Callback`. Even reading a variable outside of a Callback is unsafe, so it should be:

```
def mod(f: Seq[Todo] => Seq[Todo]): Callback =
  Callback(todos = f(todos))
```

(See scalajs-react's [Ref.scala](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/japgolly/scalajs/react/Ref.scala) an example of safely working with a variable.)

Secondly, with regards to your larger snippet, scalajs-react is very FP friendly but that's very unconventional way of trying to use it, and has some significant problems:

- `StateInterpreter.interpet` isn't referentially-transparent; there's shared global state underlying that. Fails the FP test. Stops being a lawful natural transformation.
- You're tracking two sets of identical state separately: the component state and the state in `TodoModel` (impure, fails the FP test). Not only is this approach redundant and runs the risk of the two states getting out-of-sync, but it also makes the component less reusable; imagine you decided to draw it twice on the same screen for the same data - they're going to go out of sync. Best to keep the component stateless and pure.
- If you're going to transform a free structure into a component effect, it's best to transform it into a state monad, see [here](https://japgolly.github.io/scalajs-react/#examples/state-monad) for an example.

It's really, really awesome that you're learning about free monads and scalajs-react. FP will make your entire program really, really easy to reason about and prevent confusing surprises in behaviour, but you've got to not cut any corners and make sure that you keep all of your code pure. *Any* impurity will render the entire stack all the way up to the entrypoint impure and remove those nice dependable FP properties from those layers. I'd suggest making everything as pure as possible using the points above as starting points, and then I think you'll find that the bug just disappears, or at least is very easy to then detect. Cheers

Comment: Thank you! (1) The `StateInterpreter` should simulate an external storage. (2) You are right. I will add todos only to the state in `TodoModel` and copy it into the component state: `$.props.flatMap(P => P.model.add(t)) >> $.modState((S, P) => S.copy(P.model.todos))` (3) Regarding the state monad: I could not find a method where I have access to Props and the component State like in (2).

Comment: And, of course, the bug disappeared after the changes :-). I am a big fan of FP but still a beginner.

Comment: Great to hear that the bug disappeared after making it all pure, good work! Regarding a (S, P) => S in the React state monad, oh, you're right, that's missing. But you can achieve the same thing by lifting `$.props` into the React state monad shape, method is `retM` (https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/blob/master/scalaz-7.2/src/main/scala/japgolly/scalajs/react/internal/ScalazReactState.scala#L80)

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a small `retM` code example for the "achieve the same thing by lifting `$.props` into the React state monad shape"?

Comment: I tried `(for (P <- ST.retM($.props)) yield ST.mod(S => S.copy(P.model.todos))`. But I cannot `.liftCB` it. What is the correct way?

Comment: No that's not how Scala for comprehensions work, do this:

for {
  p <- ST.retM($.props);
  _ <- ST.mod(_.copy(p.model.todos))
} yield ()

or even just ST.retM($.props).flatMap(p => ST.mod(_.copy(p.model.todos)))